# How to do Dpdk binding with bonding interface

Tags: networking, linux-networking

In server1(ubuntu 22.04.2), I have 2 physical 10G port : port1 & port2 and their respective interfaces. Now I have another interface named bond0 which has 2 slave interfaces (the 2 physical ports interfaces). I have some ip's assigned to the bond0 interface. I have previously binded dpdk to single physical interfaces where I manually handled arp/ICMP messages for IP resolve (L2 resolves where I manually replied to arp messages for my IP) and then mainly UDP ones. But I am confused how to do the things for bonding interfaces.

More info: 2 physical port from server1 is connected to 2 different switches which eventully gets connected to 2 physical ports of server2. One switch is actually for backup and I mainly want to send traffic from server2 to server1 and wanna have updated arp table in server2.

How to do this dpdk binding with bonding interface and is there better solution available?